# iOS7 - previous view pollute next view while pushing

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, ios7

I have a `XTableViewController`. When I click its cell, the `navigationController` will push to the next `YViewController`.

While the push animation, cells in the `XTableView` are still visible in the `YView`, which is abnormal:

[image]

What even worse is that the cells will not move outside the visible area smoothly, it will stick on the way and disappear suddenly. I don't want this behavior. I want a normal push animation, which doesn't have any overlap between two views.

I am sorry that I totally have no idea about this unexpected effect, so I don't know what info I should provide. Please let me know if any info about my project is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to transparent contents of iOS 7. In iOS 7 your views are transparent and when you  navigate from one view to another view contents of previous views are visible, in order to get rid off from it you change the background color of your view from transparent to another color and then you will be able to get rid off it. You can change the background color of the view:

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```